# Printing value if '1' is in 2d list

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make deck using for loops, and I made the deck, but I need to make 1 an ace, 10 a king and so on. I tried doing it with 1, but when I search for it in the list, it takes anything with a 1 and prints it. How do I print only the '1'.

```
deck = []

  signs = ["\u2660","\u2661","\u2662","\u2663"]
  for j in range(1,14):
    for i in signs:
      deck.append([str(j),str(i)])


  print(deck,'\n')

  for x in range(len(deck)):
    if str(1) in (deck[x][0]):
      print(deck[x][0])
```

Comment: You want `==` (equality test), not `is` (object identity check).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the line:

```
 if str(1) in (deck[x][0]):
```

You probably want:

```
 if str(1) == (deck[x][0]):
```

Since `in` checks that the number has a 1 in it, whereas `==` checks that the number *is* 1.